# Inserting Linux command output into MySQL within Bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have a script that scans an IP address for an open FTP port and then inputs that IP address into a MySQL database. However, upon running the script, I receive the following message:

"ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '192.168.1.104
INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES (192.168.1.104)' at line 1"

I have set up the database and named it 'nmapscans' with a table named 'users' and field name 'ip' that is of the data type 'int(20)'

Here is my incomplete script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ipadd=`ifconfig wlan0 | awk '/inet / {print $2}' | cut -d: -f2`
nmap -sV $ipadd -p 21 -oG ftp1 ; cat ftp1 | grep closed > ftp2
cut -d: -f2 ftp2 | cut -d"(" -f1 > ftp3
#cat ftp3


function checkDatabase {
    RESULT=`mysql -u root -pQwerty17 --skip-column-names -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE             'nmapscans'"`
    if [ "$RESULT" == "nmapscans" ]; then
        echo "Database exists"
    else
        echo "Database does not exist"
    fi
}

checkDatabase && echo $?

echo "INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ("100");" | mysql -uroot -pQwerty17 nmapscans;

function input_data { 
    #if [[ checkDatabase ]]
    inputfile="ftp3"
    cat $inputfile | while read ip; do
        echo "$ip"
        echo "INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ("$ip");"
    done | mysql -uroot -pQwerty17 nmapscans;
    #fi 
}

input_data && echo $?

if [[ input_data == 0 ]]
    then 
        echo "it worked" && rm ftp1 ftp2 ftp3
    else    
        echo "it failed"
fi
exit
```

Comment: You're echoing the IP in between your mysql insert statments. `Mysql` doesn't know what to do with that. Just remove the `echo "$ip"
` line.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu Great! that worked. However, something that is still confusing me is when I run the script, the status code for the input_data function is 0 but the output of the if statement at the end of the script says 'it failed'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're echoing the `IP` in between your `mysql insert` statements. `Mysql` doesn't know what to do with that. Just remove the `echo "$ip"`  line.

Change:

```
function input_data { 
    #if [[ checkDatabase ]]
    inputfile="ftp3"
    cat $inputfile | while read ip; do
        echo "$ip"
        echo "INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ("$ip");"
    done | mysql -uroot -pQwerty17 nmapscans;
    #fi 
}
```

to:

```
function input_data { 
    #if [[ checkDatabase ]]
    inputfile="ftp3"
    cat $inputfile | while read ip; do
        echo "INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ("$ip");"
    done | mysql -uroot -pQwerty17 nmapscans;
    #fi 
}
```

Also regarding your question about the return statement. Change:

```
input_data && echo $?

if [[ input_data == 0 ]]
    then 
        echo "it worked" && rm ftp1 ftp2 ftp3
    else    
        echo "it failed"
fi
exit
```

to:

```
input_data 

if [[ $? == 0 ]]
    then 
        echo "it worked" && rm ftp1 ftp2 ftp3
    else    
        echo "it failed"
fi
exit
```

Comment: Amazingly it worked. Thanks for your support and prompt reply.

Comment: The proper, idiomatic way to test for success is simply `if input_data; then` ... or even just `input_data && rm ftp[123] || echo "it failed" >&2`

Answer (score 2):

You only miss proper quoting:

```
    echo "INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ('"$ip"');"
    #                                    ^     ^
```

Thus, the IP address is quoted as a string, producing that (now valid) SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ('192.168.1.104');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error message even after having made the suggested change. I also changed the datatype of the column in MySQL to char but still no luck.

Comment: @UmairK See my comment above.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu Thank you Florin for pointing out those various issues. BTW, how `192.168.1.104` could be properly understood by MySQL as an `int(20)`? Obviously there is still one thing that I missed here !

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to show a message to user while still being able to redirect others to intended output. And `cat` is also not necessary here. Better not trouble it.

Sending the message to stderr (default `&2`) instead:

```
while read ip; do
    echo "$ip" >&2
    echo "INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ($ip);"
done < "$inputfile" | mysql -uroot -pQwerty17 nmapscans;
```

Using other file descriptors with process substitution:

```
while read ip; do
    echo "$ip"
    echo "INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ($ip);" >&4
done < "$inputfile" 4> >(exec mysql -uroot -pQwerty17 nmapscans)
```

It's also a good idea not to place your variables in the open to prevent word splitting. It may not apply now but it's still a good practice. Notice how I fixed it:

```
echo "INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ($ip);"
```

At your option you may also add  quotes:

```
echo "INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ('$ip');"
```